# VisualTreeHelper not finding children of DependencyObject, How can I reliably find objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, visualtreehelper, dependencyobject

I have a UserControl called `ZoneContainer`. This has a property that which contains a `ListBox` containing a number of `ListItem`s. Each ListItem contains a `DockPanel`.

I'm trying to use a the following code to find the children that exist inside `ZoneContainer` but `childrenCount` is 0 every time.

```
var parent = this as DependencyObject; // I can see that this is populated.

int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
```

Is there another way to find a specific child object inside a list of objects? Ultimately I'm trying to find the DockPanel, but it's not finding any children even though I know they're in the object.

Comment: Are you calling this in the constructor of `ZoneContainer`?

Comment: @Clemens, yes I am... and I think I can see where your question is going. The objects haven't been created yet?

Comment: Yes, try doing it in a [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by querying the objects rather than crawling the visual tree.

```
var header = container.ListBox.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>()
    .Select(item => (MyType) item.Content)
    .FirstOrDefault(myType => myType.dpHeader.Name == "whatever").dpHeader;
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem here is that not all childs are part of the VisualTree
You can find more information about this problem in this [articel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in) from Josh Smith

here are my extension to get all Childs

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> getChilds(this DependencyObject parent)
    {
        if (parent == null) yield break;

        //use the logical tree for content / framework elements
        foreach (object obj in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent))
        {
            var depObj = obj as DependencyObject;
            if (depObj != null)
                yield return depObj;
        }

        //use the visual tree for Visual / Visual3D elements
        if (parent is Visual || parent is Visual3D)
        {
            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the function I've got lurking in my library. I've never had any trouble with it, but it does have a GetChildrenCount() call in it so if that's not working for you you may have a bigger problem.

```
Public Shared Function FindVisualChild(Of T As DependencyObject)(ByVal element As DependencyObject) As T
    If element Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    ElseIf TypeOf (element) Is T Then
        Return element
    Else
        Dim count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element)
        For index As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, index)
            If TypeOf (child) Is T Then
                Return child
            Else
                Dim grandchild As T = FindVisualChild(Of T)(child)
                If grandchild IsNot Nothing Then Return grandchild
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Usage: x = FindVisualChild(Of DockPanel)(ParentObject)

Yes, I know it's VB. It's about time one of you C# guys had to convert code for once! :)